# Should the component size in ECS framework be less than half of the CPU line size?

Tags: c++, game-engine

I'm working on my game engine based on the ECS framework.
I have not care much about the size of an component before. While today I learnt something about the cpu cache, and it's said that generally the cache line size is 64 Bytes.

So should I always keep the size of an component lower than half of the cache line size (32 Bytes), in order to take the advantage of cpu cache ?

Comment: Where did you get the half from? do your components generally come in pairs?

Comment: With component size less than half of the line size, the cpu can put at least two component in one cache line, so only one cache miss to read 4 continuous component data. If the component size happen to be equal to one line size, then one cache miss per reading, even worse than maybe 68 Bytes. Am I right ?

Comment: Not really, if you are accessing sequentially, the CPU can often prefetch. What might be more important is keeping the overall volume of data below the total cache size. But you have to measure to know for sure.

Comment: I got it. Prefetch will do cache loading as long as I keep components data continuous in memory, just as ECS does. Thank you.